# How to initiate movement and fix arrays in brackets program

Tags: javascript, brackets

I'm currently working on a basic snake game using Brackets which contains HTML5, CSS, and JS functions. I'm a self taught coder and recently I've hit a road block with the JavaScript functions. I'm trying to initiate the snake movement (which I am totally lost on and that code is beyond help) and make an array that contains 5 body segments at the start of the game. From there, I should be able to figure out the movements and adding on more body segments to the array.

Below is my code so far, I know it's a bit messy, this is my first attempt at a full working game, the most I've really done before this is create posters an a text-based adventure game.

**SnakeBody** is the array that I have set up to hold the body segments of the snake.
**ctx** is a shorten form of context where its stemming from "theCanvas.getContext("2d")" sequence when initiating the canvas object.
**cw** is my own shortened form of "theCanvas.width" to describe the width of the canvas, and **ch** is also shortened from "theCanvas.height" to describe the height of the canvas.

My plan for this segment of code was to use genSnakeBody() to generate the next portion of the snake's body, and then use the drawSnake() function for draw the image of the snake on the canvas.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!!

```
function genSnakeBody() {
    var BodyHeight = 15 // Height of the snake's body
    var BodyWidth = 15 //Width of the snake's body
    var BodySpeed = 10 //Speed of the snake

    var body = {
        x: cw / 2 - (BodyHeight / 2),
        y: ch / 2 - (BodyWidth / 2),
        h: BodyHeight,
        w: BodyWidth,
        color: "green",
        speed: BodySpeed
    };
    var length = 5;

    SnakeBody.push(body)
}

function drawSnake() {
    var length = 5
    for (i = 0; i < SnakeBody.length; i++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = SnakeBody[i].color;
        ctx.fillRect(SnakeBody[i].x, SnakeBody[i].y, SnakeBody[i].w, SnakeBody[i].h);
        ctx.strokeRect(SnakeBody[i].x, SnakeBody[i].y, SnakeBody[i].w, SnakeBody[i].h);
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}
```

I was hoping that this would make a 5 segment snake when the page was loaded.

Instead I have a single box given the dimensions in the center of the screen, I don't know if the other boxes (if my code even allows for the other boxes) are underneath the one that I can see, or if they simply don't exist.

Like I said before, any and all help is greatly appreciated and I look forward to it!! Thank you so much if you took the time to read this and try to offer up a solution, if the code is that bad I'll try creating a cleaner version of what I have and attempt this problem from a different angle. Thank You!

Comment: What are `SnakeBody` and `ctx` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: I'll revise the question and post it again! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to keep the minimal amount of changes to you script here is a working code snippet:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var cw = 200;
var ch = 200;
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var SnakeBody = []

function genSnakeBody(index) {
  var BodyHeight = 15; // Height of the snake's body
  var BodyWidth = 15; //Width of the snake's body
  var BodySpeed = 10; //Speed of the snake

  var body = {
    x: cw / 2 - (BodyHeight / 2) * index,
    y: ch / 2 - (BodyWidth / 2) * index,
    h: BodyHeight,
    w: BodyWidth,
    color: "green",
    speed: BodySpeed
  };

  SnakeBody.push(body)
}

function drawSnake() {
  var length = 5;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    genSnakeBody(i);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = SnakeBody[i].color;
    ctx.fillRect(SnakeBody[i].x, SnakeBody[i].y, SnakeBody[i].w, SnakeBody[i].h);
    ctx.strokeRect(SnakeBody[i].x, SnakeBody[i].y, SnakeBody[i].w, SnakeBody[i].h);
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

drawSnake();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Apart from the missing variables (which are some wild guess) here the few thing that were added:

- call `genSnakeBody` with an index so it can differenciate each body part when called from within the loop
- remove the variable `length` from `genSnakeBody` function that wasn't used
- Call `genSnakeBody` inside the drawSnake `loop`